# Laravel: Get only users with 'user' role from users table

Tags: php, laravel

**I have** `users, roles` table where each `user` **have attached** one `role` in the `role_user` table. I **need to get** in my `UserController` **all users with role name 'user'** associated in `role_user` (exclude admins).

**I currently have this:**

`UserController:`

```
class UserController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $users = User::all(); // Get here only users with role 'user' in role_user table

        return view( 'admin.users.index' )
            ->with( 'users', $users )
        ;
    }
}
```

`create_users_table:`

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    public function up() {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

`create_roles_table:`

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration {

    public function up() {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

`create_role_user_table:`

```
class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration {

    public function up() {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('user_id')->unique();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

How can accomplish that?

Comment: Try elequent instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in User.php Model:

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
```

in your controller:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles' , function($q){
   $q->whereName('user');
})->get();
```

Comment: Great thanks!! `$query->where( 'name', 'user' );` works too.